# Android - Can’t add Okhttp dependency with Estimote SDK

Tags: java, android, picasso, okhttp

Good evening,

I'm triying to add OkHttp library to my Android project, which uses Estimote Android SDK. It seems that the Estimote Android SDK has included that library (an older version), but the problem is that other dependencies I have included to my app (like Picasso) can't access to that dependencies, just my own classes can. Picasso, to initialize the image caching system, needs to instantiate OkHttpClient object by his own and this class can be found in the OkHttp library. But, it seems that a dependency can't access to another dependencies' library. I don't really know how to explain it...

If I add the OkHttp dependency to my Gradle, after 7 minutes of building, the build fails with a "dexDebug" error. That means that the same library is included twice (one in the Estimote SDK and other in my Gradle).

Here you can see my Gradle's dependencies field:

```gradle
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    //compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.6.0.jar')
    compile(name: 'estimote-sdk', ext: 'aar') // This library has okhttp 2.2.0 included in it, but Picasso library can't access here...
}
```

Here you can see the piece of code that needs the Okhttp library.

```c#
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
OkHttpDownloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
// OkHttpDownloader is a Picasso's class, and then this needs OkHttpClient object from OkHttp library. But it seems that a library can't access to Estimote's library.
builder.downloader(downloader);

Picasso built = builder.build();
built.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
built.setLoggingEnabled(true);

Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);
```

Then, if the problem is solved, I want to change all my HttpRequest AsyncTasks to OkHttp requests.

Any ideas how to solve it? Maybe I can make something in the Gradle file, but I don't know what can I do...

Thank you very much.

Happy coding.

Comment: "This library has okhttp 2.2.0 included in it" -- make sure you have the latest AAR. I see it was updated ~16 hours ago. This AAR seems to have repackaged those quasi-dependencies into different Java namespaces, to avoid collisions with your own use of those dependencies.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply!Yes, I downloaded the latest AAR and included in my project, but the problem persists. And now I tried including from Maven Central and the same happens.